# When started from another activity ListView is not working

Tags: android, android-listview

When I run the app and click on the button to bring this up, it says that the app has stopped. Any help toward this would be greatly appreciated
This is the bulk of my code:

```
public class MainActivity2 extends ListActivity {
ListView listView;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ListView theListView = getListView();

    Intent calledActivity=getIntent();
    final List pe=calledActivity.getExtras().getStringArrayList("Caller1");
           ListAdapter theAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pe);

    theListView.setAdapter(theAdapter);
    theListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String s = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
            pe.remove(s);
        }
    });
```

XML:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

LOGCAT:

```
01-23 16:03:29.501    1147-1147/com.example.epiclapser.noprocrastinate W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-23 16:03:29.541    1147-1147/com.example.epiclapser.noprocrastinate D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
01-23 16:04:24.422    1147-1147/com.example.epiclapser.noprocrastinate D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 273K, 16% free 2746K/3244K, paused 76ms, total 105ms
01-23 16:04:24.552    1147-1147/com.example.epiclapser.noprocrastinate D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 63K, 17% free 2792K/3344K, paused 69ms, total 80ms
01-23 16:04:24.572    1147-1147/com.example.epiclapser.noprocrastinate I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 3.550MB for 635812-byte allocation
01-23 16:04:24.651    1147-1156/com.example.epiclapser.noprocrastinate D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 15% free 3412K/3968K, paused 82ms, total 82ms
01-23 16:04:24.742    1147-1147/com.example.epiclapser.noprocrastinate D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 15% free 3412K/3968K, paused 54ms, total 55ms
01-23 16:04:24.751    1147-1147/com.example.epiclapser.noprocrastinate I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 4.027MB for 500416-byte allocation
01-23 16:04:24.832    1147-1156/com.example.epiclapser.noprocrastinate D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 13% free 3900K/4460K, paused 76ms, total 76ms
01-23 16:04:25.001    1147-1147/com.example.epiclapser.noprocrastinate D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
01-23 16:04:25.001    1147-1147/com.example.epiclapser.noprocrastinate W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
01-23 16:04:25.082    1147-1147/com.example.epiclapser.noprocrastinate E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

Hope that the logcat helps   :)

Comment: What does getListView() do?

Comment: Yout list variable is not null you are sure about it ?

Comment: I was told that it is used instead of setContentView() which in retrospect makes no sense because its a 'get' method hmmm I used setContentViw as well but it did not work either

Comment: pretty sure its not null

Comment: If your app crashes include the exception details from LogCat

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the error you are getting is a NullPointerException since you don't initialize your listview..
how about adding :
    theListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

and then try running it again..
if it doesn't work, please add the logcat with the error you are getting!

ty.

Answer (score 0):

`ListView theListView = getListView();` change this to

```
ListView theListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);`
```

Comment: I'm in the process of doing that! Fingers crossed!

Answer (score 0):

There's a reason why the base class is called `ListActivity`. It can fetch a `ListView` with id `android.R.id.list` by calling `getListView()`.

Before that will work, however, you'll need to call `setContentView` and pass a layout that has a `ListView` with such an id.

Here's an example:

MainActivity2.java:

```
public class MainActivity2 extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ...
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Instead of relative layout I used linear layout, and instead of "activity_main" I used "Activity_main_activity1" which is the name of my second activity but it did not work

Comment: @epiclapser of course my answer was only an example. Does it work?

Comment: unfortunately no it gives me the same message

Comment: @epiclapser I don't think you've pasted the whole logcat. Can you check again?

Comment: The logcat would not fit in , I apparently had too many characters

Comment: @epiclapser use pastebin.com then.

Comment: @epiclapser it says: `Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'`. Did you set the proper id for your ListView as in my example?

Comment: @epiclapser I bet you're getting a new error now.. Pastebin it again.

Comment: This is going to be a little awkward, but uh... its way past my bedtime (yes I have one , even though I'm in highschool) are there any alternatives to a listview

Comment: @epiclapser uh sorry I can't help someone who doesn't want to be helped ^^